# Rollback changes made by @Sql(executionPhase = BEFORE_TEST_METHOD) in spring @Transactional Test

Tags: spring, spring-test, transactional

I have test:

```
@Transactional
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
ClassServiceTest
```

And Test for method:

```
@Sql(executionPhase = BEFORE_TEST_METHOD, scripts ="test.sql")
public void methodTest() {
}
```

As far I know The @Transactional with SpringJUnit4ClassRunner makes all test sql/db changes to rollback. Would @Sql script executed before method will be rollbacked to?

Answer (score 2):

You can use SqlGroup annotation to manually control db changes:

```
@SqlGroup({
        @Sql(executionPhase = BEFORE_TEST_METHOD, scripts = "/sql/insert_data.sql"),
        @Sql(executionPhase = AFTER_TEST_METHOD, scripts = "/sql/drop_data.sql")
})
```